# Cannot install netbeans plugin - netbeans instalation corrupt?

Tags: macos, netbeans

While trying to install the [Node.js Projects](https://github.com/timboudreau/) plugin, it says that:

> Some plugins require plugin Progress API to be installed.
>
> The plugin Progress API is requested in version >= 1.40 but only
>   1.38.1 was found. The following plugin is affected:       Node.js Projects
>
> Some plugins require plugin Ant-Based Project Support to be installed.
>
> The plugin Ant-Based Project Support is requested in version >= 1.62
>   but only 1.60.1 was found. The following plugin is affected:
>   Node.js Projects
>
> Some plugins require plugin File System API to be installed.
>
> The plugin File System API is requested in version >= 9.0 but only
>   8.12.1 was found. The following plugin is affected:       Node.js Projects
>
> Some plugins require plugin Datasystems API to be installed.
>
> The plugin Datasystems API is requested in version >= 7.61 but only
>   7.57.2 was found. The following plugin is affected:       Node.js Projects
>
> Some plugins require plugin Utilities API to be installed.
>
> The plugin Utilities API is requested in version >= 9.3 but only
>   8.39.1 was found. The following plugin is affected:       Node.js Projects
>
> Some plugins require plugin org.openide.util.ui to be installed.
>
> The plugin org.openide.util.ui is requested in version 9.3. The
>   following plugin is affected:       Node.js Projects Some plugins not
>   installed to avoid potential installation problems.

I asked the author of the plugin, and he said that [my netbeans version is ancient](https://github.com/timboudreau/nb-nodejs/issues/37).

The thing is this is a freshly installed netbeans and have tried to cleanup every cache and setting found on my system, I have removed:

- /Applications/NetBeans/
- ~/Library/Application Support/NetBeans
- ~/Library/Caches/NetBeans
- /private/var/db/receipts/org.netbeans.*

Tried on netbeans: 8.0.1 PHP, 8.0.2 full
OSX: Mavericks, updated
Plugin version: 2.21

[image: screenshot of netbeans version]

Tried to install plugin both as an .npm and from the authors [update site](http://timboudreau.com/modules). The plugin is not yet available in the official update center.

I have a second mac where the plugin works fine (NetBeans 8.0.0, OSX Mountain Lion), so this can be installed, but somehow on this system this install is stuck with an outdated plugin version somewhere in the system.

How to fully reset my netbeans instalation?

---

Additional information after some checks:

1. It is not dependant on user, newly created user has the same problem - so not a problem with any file in $HOME
2. It is the only instalation of netbeans on the computer, there was a [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/) tool embeded into the system JRE, but removing it didn't help.
3. I tried a `dtruss` (OSX `strace` equivalent, monitors system calls) on NetBeans, and it is not [opening any suspicious files](https://gist.github.com/chanibal/b08267e58e83e8138387) - only from JRE and NB 8.0.2's folder.

Comment: which version currently you are using...?Try to download the plugin from Update Center.

Comment: information updated (the plugin is not available from the official update center, using author's)

Comment: Added a question on [the official NetBeans forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=161001#161001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the plugin [has released a patch](https://github.com/timboudreau/nb-nodejs/issues/37) that fixed the versioning issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error Clearly shows that you are using older version of netbeans, or your netbean is not successfully upgraded.

see the version of  plugin org.openide.util.ui is [9.3](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util-ui/index.html?org/openide/LifecycleManager.html) and in error it is showing 8.39.1

If you just drag the netbean directory to thrash it will be removed from your OSX and also clear the Cache of Netbean. After that download and install a fresh copy of NetBeans.

> Note that NetBeans leaves some hidden configuration directories in your home directory. You might want to delete those too:
>
> .asadminpass and .asadmintruststore - directories that contain stuff for Glassfish (Java EE application server)
>
> .netbeans and .netbeans-registration - NetBeans configuration directories
>
> .nbprofiler - something from the NetBeans profiler
>
> In a terminal window, you can list all files and directories (including hidden ones) with ls -la, and you can delete them with for example rm -rf .netbeans (BE CAREFUL with that last command, it deletes stuff so that you can't get it back). answer posted On SO by [jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135589/jesper)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014099/how-can-i-uninstall-netbeans-on-a-mac

Comment: Screenshot of current version dialog added in the question; also look at the list of folders that I have removed (also in question), all of your suggestions are either already there, or there were no such files to remove (your linked question is from NB6.5).